# Withings API: Access Shared User Measurement Data

Tags: php, withings

I am trying to access measurement data for users that have shared access to my Withings account. I can access my own measurement data, but not data for their user ids. Is this access even possible for through the API?

Whenever I change the `userid` to one other than my own, I get the error code indicating an invalid userid was given.

```
http://wbsapi.withings.net/measure?action=getmeas&startdate=122281920&userid=12345
```

gives me this in PHP

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 247
)
```

Comment: unless its a really popular API, its better to ask questions so specific to such a thing on their own support forums.

Comment: Withings doesn't have a forum and their customer support is slow to respond and somewhat unhelpful with API-level questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to customer support, it is impossible to retrieve data from any user other than the one that is authenticated.

One suggestion is to gather OAuth tokens for each user and retrieve measurements with each, separate OAuth token.